# How to create own custom TTS Library for Burmese Language

Tags: android

Can you please tell me How to create own custom TTS library that support the Burmese language
I want to create TTS library for Burmese language or otherwise tell me how to edit in the TTS file to change into Burmese language.

Please Help me out from this problem i am creating TTS application android using Burmese Language.

Comment: Hey you need to develop your own TTS Engine it's a very big Deal.Try to find how you can develop the tts engine.

Comment: Yes that Why I am asking on the stackoverflow How to make a custom TTS engine in Burmese language. If someOne have a knowledge on this Please share with me

Comment: visit the link http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php I hope it will give some idea/hint to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing,**Its not easy**

However you can do it with lots of research starting with android native Text-to-speech library.

Supporting to other language which is not supported by tts is difficult as the voice content changes and also it dependes on which TTS engine you have currently installed in your device E.g.PICO,SVOX,LOQUENDO. **and each TTS engine has their own support for language(Hindi,English,Spanish) voice(male,famale) and accent(US,UK).**

So **i recommend you to call third party**(E.g. Loquendo) and ask them for solution they may provide solution for problem or they can give you complete tts library for you language(if you pay them)

Comment: Hey Thanks Dear we have looking forward to talk to Nuance Company for Voice and Recognition.